# Notions of orthogonality for bivectors

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I need a favor to ask. Is there any notion of orthogonality for bivectors or 2-vectors? If there are share such book names / article titles.

Comment: What are bivectors?

Comment: Bivectors or 2-vectors are discussed in this link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector

Answer (score 1):

Given a vector space $V$ with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on it, we can define a [natural inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Inner_product) on the exterior powers $\Lambda^kV$ as a determinant

$$\langle x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge \dots \wedge x_k, y_1 \wedge y_2 \wedge \dots \wedge y_k\rangle = \\
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\langle x_1, y_1 \rangle & \langle x_1, y_2 \rangle & \cdots & \langle x_1, y_k \rangle \\
\langle x_2, y_1 \rangle & \langle x_2, y_2 \rangle & \cdots & \langle x_2, y_k \rangle \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle x_k, y_1 \rangle & \langle x_k, y_2 \rangle & \cdots & \langle x_k, y_k \rangle
\end{vmatrix}$$

Using this inner product, we can say that two bivectors $x, y$ (or, in general, $k$-vectors) are orthogonal if their inner product is zero: $\langle x, y\rangle = 0$.

Comment: Can you share any book or article name?

Comment: @Anirban Unfortunately, I don't know any book on the topic. The linked wikipedia article has some information, though.

Comment: There is a stronger notion of orthogonality, that the geometric product $xy=x\wedge y$. Considering $x$ and $y$ as subspaces (assuming they're simple), the weaker notion is that there's a vector in $x$ orthogonal to all vectors in $y$, and the stronger notion is that all vectors in $x$ are orthogonal to all vectors in $y$.

Comment: Please share some literatures related to this, @mr_e_man.

Comment: @Anirban - I don't have much except https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra and links therein. For bivectors $x=\langle x\rangle_2,\;y=\langle y\rangle_2$, the geometric product is $$xy=\langle xy\rangle_0+\langle xy\rangle_2+\langle xy\rangle_4$$ $$=x\bullet y\;+\;x\times y\;+\;x\wedge y.$$ Saying that $xy=x\wedge y$ is equivalent to saying that the lower-grade parts vanish; $x\bullet y=x\times y=0$, which is stronger than just $x\bullet y=0$.